# Setup SQL relationship so that Excel can link 3 tables

Tags: mysql, excel

I need to establish a relationship in an existing database containing 3 tables for 3 measurement devices A, B, C that will populate these 3 tables independently:

```
[table1] [table2] [table3]
id       id       id    
mesA_1   mesB_1   mesC_1
mesA_2   mesB_2   mesC_2
```

Each sample is assigned a unique id, and that's how we can associates the 3 sets of measurements that correspond to the same sample.
So I have to create the 3 tables and the relationship between the three id keys.
In the end I want to be able to query the database from Excel to display in a single line the measurements of the 3 devices.

I followed tutorials but most of the time they're for 2 tables and not 3. Basically I set every id key as PRIMARY but then I do not know if the relationship is two-way or not, if must chain the 3 tables or define a master and two childs. In short I'm clueless.

Comment: What are the fields used to tie these tables together? what is the common key?

Comment: The common key is "id".

Comment: @JulienM how does table2 and table3 know which ID corresponds to the information in table1?  To put it another way, does the vb code keep track of what ID is being used across the 3 tables?